# Delphi Tokyo Debug: "A debugger has been found running in your system [...]" Error

Tags: delphi, debugging

When I try to use Delphi Tokyo debugging an application that uses functions of a DLL, when I run LoadLibrary, it shows a message that there is a debugger running and does not allow loading it.

> A debugger has been found running in your system. Please, unload it from memory and restart your program.

I've disabled everything I could, antivirus, firewall, windows defender, etc ...

The DLL Manufacturer says it has no debug lock.

My suspicion may be that Windows 10, after some update, installed some mechanism to block this type of debug with LoadLibray.

Comment: Either you're trying to debug something packed with debug prevention (Themida, etc) or you have something similar installed on your system (GameGuard, etc).  Generally, workstations and gaming systems shouldn't mix.  I presume you have games installed on your system?

Comment: Almost certainly this has nothing to do with Windows and a DLL in your process is responsible for blocking your use of a debugger. The supplier of the DLL claims that their DLL is not responsible but it seems very likely that it is. In any case we can't be expected to say any more. We don't have enough detail.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Could be the DLL, could be something like GameGuard - the latter is effectively a rootkit distributed with some games.  It hooks into the OS, runs in ring zero, has its own Themida protection, and can intercept certain WinAPI calls, etc, to prevent RE and cheating mods.  An easy test would be for OP to try to debug any other DLL to see if it's specific to the DLL in question or whether it's a system-wide agent interfering.

Comment: Quick and Dirty simple test: Load the .DLL in a PE Analyzer and see if it contains a call to "IsDebuggerPresent". If it does, then that .DLL most certainly - somewhere - tests if a debugger is active.

Comment: Another option that I use sometimes is to not start the program under Tokyo, but start it outside of Tokyo and then attach to the running program after it has started up. If the .DLL only tests for debugger at startup, you can bypass that test in this way.

Comment: @HeartWare I suggest creating an answer from both your comments. They are useful tricks when encountering such a problem.

Comment: @dummzeuch but they don't answer the question that was asked, comments are fine

Comment: @DavidHeffernan in the present form, the question cannot be answered since nobody can know what the reason is on his machine with his DLL(s).

Comment: @dummzeuch correct

Comment: I still think it is a valuable question because answers (or at least comments) can give hints what to do to find the problem. And that problem is not as rare as one might think. That's why I am opposed to closing it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for all help, although the manufacturer says it had no hang in the dll, I was insistent with the developers and they assumed there was a DLL problem made in C. We returned the previous version of the DLL and it worked. Thanks again.